# mod_rewrite: prepend query string instead of appending with QSA

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a `RewriteRule` that produces a URL with a query string, since I also need to pass GET parameters I'm using the QSA option.

But QSA causes a problem. `/tenant1/index?id=5&__tenant=other_tenant` will be rewritten to `/app/index?__tenant=tenant1&id=5&__tenant=other_tenant` overriding the `__tenant=tenant1` which I don't want to happen.

Is there a way to prepend the query string so that my rewrite rule generated parameters have precedence over user provided ones?

EDIT: the rule

```
RewriteRule ^(tenant1|tenant2|demo)/(.*)$ app/$2?__tenant=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: What have your tried and where is the rule you used?

Comment: @Starkeen just posted the rule to make the problem more clear

Comment: What behavior do you expect by reusing same query parameter `__tenant` in target URI.

Comment: @anubhava I want  to preserve the first definition of tenant which is the one I'm defining in the RewriteRule.

Comment: It will still be preserved if you use: `RewriteRule ^(tenant1|tenant2|demo)/(.*)$ app/$2?__tenant1=$1 [L,NC,QSA]`

Comment: @anubhava the user may still rewrite the URL adding a tenant1=something

Comment: You can use a totally weird looking query parameter in .htaccess and since it is an internal rewrite users will never get to know your internal query parameter.